# Converting a 4x2 matrix into two 2x2 matrices?

Tags: matlab

I created a meshgrid and then converted the points to a single vector as follows:

```
gMax = 1;
gStep = 2;
[g1, g2] = meshgrid(-gMax:gStep:gMax, -gMax:gStep:gMax);
```

This gives the following output for g1 and g2:

```
g1 =

    -1     1
    -1     1

g2 =

    -1    -1
     1     1
```

Now if can convert the two matrices into a single matrix as follows:

```
gridPoints = [g1(:) g2(:)];
```

This gives the output:

```
gridPoints =

    -1    -1
    -1     1
     1    -1
     1     1
```

Now my question is: How would I turn the single 4x2 matrix of grid points back into its original form of two 2x2 matrices?

Comment: Why not just store `g1` and `g2` and use those directly?

Comment: @Suever I'm not actually looking for g1, and g2, I'm looking to recover a result at the end of several computations where I've used the gridPoints variable. I just phrased it like the above to make the question more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this for each of the columns of `gridPoints` using `reshape` to change it from a 4 x 1 into a 2 x 2.

```
g1 = reshape(gridPoints(:,1), [2 2]);
g2 = reshape(gridPoints(:,2), [2 2]);
```

You can generalize this to any square size of `g1` and `g2`.

```
g1 = reshape(gridPoints(:,1), sqrt(size(gridPoints, 1)), []);   
g2 = reshape(gridPoints(:,2), sqrt(size(gridPoints, 1)), []);
```

Comment: Ok, that works thanks. Now what about if g1 and g2 are 3x3 matrices? Essentially, I'd like it to work for g1 and g2 of size nxn, if that's possible?

Comment: g1 and g2 will always be square yes.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems there's a problem if I set gStep = 1 as this gives me an error: Error using reshape. Size arguments must be real integers.